# Get all the entries alphabetically preceding a certain entry (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am looking for a way to solve such a problem. 
For example,  I have a table of clients and I need to get all the clients who come alphabetically (name) before a client with a number 123.
 For example:

```
ID  name
500 Anny
145 Bob
454 Cindy
789 Dan
123 Eve
400 Fred
```

I'd get Anny, Bob, Cindy and Dan.
I am using postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select c.*
from clients c
where c.name < (select c2.name from clients c2 where c2.id = 123)
order by c.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a self-join:

```
SELECT c2.*
FROM   clients c1
JOIN   clients c2 ON c2.name < c1.name
WHERE  c1.id = 123
ORDER  BY c2.name;
```